# Is there a way where you can select multiple html elements from javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am having a HTML file with multiple svg elements. I want to add an event listner on all of them but I do not want to use querySelector. Is there any other way we can achieve this functionality?

I tried with the document.querySelector element.

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll`